# Private social network SaaS (for integration with Salesforce)

Tags: api, social-networks

I'm currently investigating SaaS solutions for implementing social network like activity on a client's site, such as activity feeds, message boards, leaderboards, add/delete friends/followers; things like that.

It would need to be able to integrate into the client's current CRM system (Salesforce) as well as their existing site; we don't want a separate site to send users to see their friends' activities and other things like that. Therefore, we need a solution with a robust API we can work with to integrate into our current site.

I've looked at Lithium and SocialEngine; but want to see if there are other options I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution for social network for a private or corporate solution is [BlaBlanet Social Network](https://blablanet.com/) wherein:

- Ability to setup a [private directory and satellite nodes](https://blablanet.com/directory) for make independent of the rest of networks.
- You can ask or make one issue in the project in GitHub about how to or any feature you will like to have if is a private project they support
- Ability to utilize CalDAV and CardDAV and bridge with a CRM like SugarCRM

You can see a list of their applications [here](https://blablanet.com/apps).

Comment: the domain blabalnet.com is for sale. Is there a typo?